# In js replace where do escape, str, and hex come from in "replace(/%(7C|60|5E)/g, (str, hex) =>" and "replace(/['()]/g, escape)"

Tags: javascript

I must be looking at the wrong replace [api documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for replace but I can't find another definition. The code from the MDN on [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)() has a callback called `escape` that appears to be native javascript not in the definition of replace I found. It also has parameters to the callback called `str` and `hex` that don't match the possible values specified for replace callback `replace(//g, callback(match, p1, p2, offset, string));` Where does this replace come from? An explanation, or better a link to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

```
 encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/['()]/g, escape). // i.e., %27 %28 %29

 encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%(7C|60|5E)/g, (str, hex) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16)));
```

I know they're not trying to trick me, because I tried it on my console

```
encodeURIComponent('my file(2).txt').replace(/['()]/g, escape);
> "my%20file%282%29.txt"
```

Comment: MDN says: `str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)` <-- the second parameter is a callback function. It also lists all arguments this callback function receives below: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter - `hex` is the first parenthesized submatch string matched by `(7C|60|5E)`. The name of the callback function's parameters doesn't matter, as long as the order is according to the specification.

Comment: In JavaScript, a function can be invoked without including all parameters. For instance: function test(a) {console.log(a); } can be invoked as test(); without throwing an error. so (str, hex) => {} is a callback that only uses the first two parameters, in this case match and p1.

Comment: @programmingforfun I see, so you have to know ahead of time the exact number of matches that will be found. You can't use the name of the parameter to indicate which parameters you are accepting. And where is escape, unescape defined? Must be an undocumented feature. Actually, I see now- The number of parameters will be the number of parentheses in the regex search. Not the number of global matches.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Right here: [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape), [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

Comment: @Derek GREAT! I'm relatively new on SO. I got my answer. No MOD will come along and deactivate my account if I delete the question? I think this would only help me because of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @user5389726598465 You can just leave it open, won't do any harm.

Comment: in short, `encodeURIComponent('my file(2).txt').replace(/['()]/g, escape);` is pretty much the same as `"my%20file(2).txt".replace(/['()]/g, function (match, p1, p2, offset, string) { return escape(match) })`